# Check Checkbox depending on value in database

Tags: php, mysql

I have an code that gets the 'branches' from the database. Each company can have multiple 'branches'.

Only thing is, that is doesn't work. Can you guys figure out what's wrong?

```
$getbranches = "SELECT * FROM branches ORDER BY naam ASC";
$querygetbranches = mysql_query($getbranches);

while($rijbranche = mysql_fetch_assoc($querygetbranches))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td width='400'>";
    echo $rijbranche['naam'];
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    $get2 = "SELECT * FROM bedrijf_branche WHERE bedrijf_id = '$id'";
    $query2 = mysql_query($get2);
    while ($rij20 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query2))
    {
        $branche_id = $rij20['branche_id'];
    }
    if($branche_id == $rijbranche['id_branche']){
        ?>
        <input type="checkbox" name="branche[]" value="<?php echo $rijbranche['id_branche']; ?>" CHECKED></input>
        <?php
    }
    else
    {
        ?>
        <input type="checkbox" name="branche[]" value="<?php echo $rijbranche['id_branche']; ?>"></input>
        <?php
    }
    echo "</td>";
}
```

Comment: When you say "It doesn't work" what do you mean?

Comment: When there are 2 branches, only 1 comes up checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code

```
<?php

$id = $_GET['id'];

// Output BRANCHES
$getbranches = "SELECT * FROM branches ORDER BY naam ASC";
$querygetbranches = mysql_query($getbranches);

while ($rijbranche = mysql_fetch_array($querygetbranches)) {
  echo '  <tr>' . "\n";
  echo '    <td width="400">' . $rijbranche['naam'] . '</td>' . "\n";

  // Output CHECKBOX
  $get2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bedrijf_branche WHERE bedrijf_id = '" . $id . "' AND branche_id = '" . $rijbranche['id_branche'] . "'");
  $rij20 = mysql_fetch_array($get2);
  $branche_id = $rij20['branche_id'];

  if ($branche_id == $rijbranche['id_branche']) {
    $checkbox = '<input type="checkbox" name="branche[]" value="' . $rijbranche['id_branche'] . '" checked="checked" />';
  }
  else {
    $checkbox = '<input type="checkbox" name="branche[]" value="' . $rijbranche['id_branche'] . '" />';
  }

  echo '    <td>' . $checkbox . '</td>' . "\n";
  echo '  </tr>' . "\n";
}

?>
```

Found a couple of errors I fixed in the above code.

1. You're closing the `<input>` fields incorrectly
2. Your second `while()` loop is unnecessary as there should only be one row returned
3. You have to add `branche_id` to your second mysql_query!
4. Don't close and re-open your `<?php ?>` tags for every HTML line when you can just add an `echo`

Comment: $id is defined already (top of the page), sorry that I didn't mention that. And yes $branche_id is correct ;)! If/else inside the while loop causes the following: two rows with checkboxes with in each row one selected checkbox. We're getting there :)

Comment: @AndreWoons - huh? Can you give me a link to a live example so that I can see what it is that's wrong

Comment: www.blinks.nl/cms (login = admin / test ) , go to http://www.blinks.nl/cms/bedrijven-edit.php?id=1&action=edit

Comment: @AndreWoons - Is it "Branches bewerken"? The list with names followed by 3 checkboxes? What exactly is wrong with the current output?

Comment: Yep it is! I want one row with the three boxes checked, so that i can edit the branches. Cause the update / edit stuff works, only showing wich branches are currently selected does not work (proper, in one row)

Comment: @AndreWoons - What is your $id set to? Can you update your post with an overview of how your bedrijf_branche database table looks like?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7762/discussion-between-andre-woons-and-tom)

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML-syntax is wrong.
The way you close the input tag and the way you want to check the chechbox is wrong
Try this

```
    <input type="checkbox" name="branche[]" value="<?php echo $rijbranche['id_branche']; ?>" checked="checked" />
```